# What is this `adb` utility I keep getting advice to use?

Tags: adb, shell

In a bunch of questions on this site I see answers telling us to execute `adb shell` or `adb logcat` and so on.

Now, I'm not an entirely clueless user, so I downloaded and installed Termux and have a shell prompt when I can type in commands, but - where does this `adb` thing come from? Do I download it as an app? It doesn't seem to be installed by default (On a Redmi 3S, Android 6.0.1).

Also, it seems like it's some kind of permission elevator. Is it like `su`? If not, how is it different?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html, https://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378

Comment: @RahulGopi: Yes, I just think there could be a succinct answer here on the site.

Comment: It's the tool described in our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info), with resources linked – told ya that before I guess :) Remember: Many of our tags have decent wikis :) Also see, here on our very site: [What's ADB and why is it used for? How do I install it on my device?](/q/40024/16575)

Comment: The [ADB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus) is used to connect mouses and keyboards to state-of-the-art computers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### About `adb`

To put it shortly, `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) is a utility made to be installed on a computer, in order to let it gain a shell on a phone that's either connected via USB cable, or on the same Wi-Fi network.

On certain devices running Android Lollipop (5.1.1) and possibly lower versions of the OS, it was possible to trick a device into connecting to itself, since the `adb` client came bundled in the phone as well. This is *not possible any more* because, from Android Marshmallow (6.0) onwards, *Google removed the `adb` binary* from the phones to reduce the usable attack surface.

It is possible, though, to manually reintroduce the `adb` client on a phone, without needing to compile the binary yourself. Refer to the [adb tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for more info about this topic, as well as about installation on a computer and general troubleshooting.

---

### Where to get it

Some time ago, in order to obtain `adb` and another utility, called `fastboot`, one had to download the full Android SDK from Google, if they wanted an official package. Nowadays, a small, official bundle has become available, [as XDA says](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads/). It includes binaries for the most common operating systems.

---

### How it works

The `adb` client, installed on your computer, makes a connection to a plugged or otherwise detectable phone, by means of an internal server. Then, the user will be able to send a variety of commands to the phone itself, which will be listened to by `adbd`, a daemon residing on the phone.

When using `adb`, you impersonate the user called `shell` (UID `2000`). This user is special, in that they can grant app permissions and access more information than a simple user. This fact, though, does not mean that `adb` is the same as `su`, as the latter lets you impersonate any user.

More info about `adb` and its workings may be obtained by looking at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html).

---

### Issuing commands from a phone

The majority of commands that can be issued via `adb` tend to be utilities that come preinstalled in a phone.

In order to access them, you need to install a terminal emulator app on your phone (note that Termux is special, in that it specifies its own `PATH`, thereby ignoring system binaries). This will, for example, let you issue commands such as `logcat` directly on your mobile device. *Remember to omit the `adb` prefix, though.*

It is worth mentioning that, should you lack root permissions, the range of commands you'll be able to execute and the info you'll be able to access will be significantly less than if using `adb`, because the UID that invokes them will be the app itself, and apps have less permissions than UID `2000`.

Comment: Well done! Unfortunately I cannot upvote twice :) // Yeah, our wikis are far too often "unknown quantities". Cannot point there often enough. But including a link in any answer mentioned in it is going a bit far IMHO :) Where it fits (like here: "for further details …"), a good idea. Feel free to go ahead with that – I go ahead for comment cleanup meanwhile :)

Comment: @Izzy Good point. Let's wait and see if link spamming is actually needed.

Comment: Have my upvote, please.

Comment: @iBug I am honored.

Answer (score 2):

**Android Debugging Bridge (ADB)**.

It sends commands over USB or Wifi to an android device. It is typically installed on the computer connected to the device. The ADB client can also be run on device itself however the idea is to remotely debug the device.

It is part of the [Android Software Development Kit](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

You can then use the SDK manager to download platform tools.

There is also a more direct link here in case you're just interested in the 
[platform tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html)

[ADB Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html)

Comment: Wait, if it's not installed on the device, why do people suggest I use it in shells on the device? e.g. in the examples I gave?

Comment: Thats a good point. Maybe its more correct to say adb command is the "client" connecting to a android device. The android device can also have the client on it because why not. But thats sorta like running ssh localhost

Comment: To be honest the documentation explains all this well: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html